# How to solve this recurrence relation for a general $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

We have a recurrence relation:

$$a_n=1$$
$$a_{n-1}=x$$
$$a_{n-i}=xa_{n-i+1}-a_{n-i+2} $$ for $i=2,3,\ldots,n.$

How to find $a_0$ in terms of $x$? For a fixed $n$, I can solve it but it turns out very tedious for large $n$. I thought of guessing the cofficient of a general $a_i$ after finding $a_i$'s upto $i=n-10$ but to no avail. Can you help me to find $a_0$ for any given $n$?

Comment: Do you know how to work with generating functions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Let me google it.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf) text, I think is very good and have good examples to solve problems like you want.

Comment: @ Masacroso, I reformulated the question as: $ a_0=1, a_1=x, a_i=xa_{i-1}-a_{i-2}$ for $i=2,3,\ldots,n$ and then tried to find out $a_n$. Then I multiplied the last equation by $x^1$  and took summation from 2 to $\infty$ .Suppose $a(x)=\sum a_ix^i$ was generating function. So after solving the above equation I got $a(x)=1$, then comparing coefficient of $x^n$ gives me $a_n=0$ :( Where am I wrong. I just followed the steps given in the text you refered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use linear algebra. We can write the recurrence relation as follows:

\begin{equation}\left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-i}\\a_{n-i+1} \end{array} \right) = M_x \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-i+1}\\a_{n-i+2} \end{array} \right)\end{equation}

where $i \geq 2$ and

\begin{equation}M_x=\left( \begin{array}{cc} x&-1\\1&0\end{array} \right)\end{equation}

So, for instance, we have that:

\begin{equation}\left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-2}\\a_{n-1} \end{array} \right) = M_x \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-1}\\a_{n} \end{array} \right)\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}\left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-3}\\a_{n-2} \end{array} \right) = M_x \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-2}\\a_{n-1} \end{array} \right) = (M_x)^2 \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-1}\\a_{n} \end{array} \right)\end{equation}

So, in the end we'll have

\begin{equation}\left( \begin{array}{c} a_{0}\\a_{1} \end{array} \right) = (M_x)^{n-1} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} a_{n-1}\\a_{n} \end{array} \right) = (M_x)^{n-1} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} x\\1 \end{array} \right)\end{equation}

So now your solution hinges on your ability to calculate $(M_x)^{n-1}$. Do you think you can take it from here? A hint: diagonalization.

EDIT: We have that $M_x$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = \frac12\cdot(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})$ and $\lambda_2 = \frac12\cdot(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})$. We may diagonalize it as $M_x = PDP^{-1}$ with

\begin{equation}P=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \lambda_1&\lambda_2\\1&1\end{array} \right)\end{equation}

\begin{equation}D=\left( \begin{array}{cc} \lambda_1&0\\ 0&\lambda_2\end{array} \right)\end{equation}

\begin{equation}P^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&-\lambda_2\\-1&\lambda_1\end{array} \right)\end{equation}

Working out $(M_x)^n$ we get that $$a_0 = \frac{({\lambda_1}^n-{\lambda_2}^n)x-({\lambda_1}^n\lambda_2 -{\lambda_2}^n\lambda_1)}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$$

Using that $$a^n-b^n = (a-b)\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^k$$we may simplify the expression to$$a_0 = x\cdot\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\lambda_1}^{n-1-k}{\lambda_2}^k\right)-\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdot\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}{\lambda_1}^{n-2-k}{\lambda_2}^k\right)$$

You can check for the first few values of $n$ that these are indeed polynomials in $x$:

\begin{equation}\begin{array}{cccccc}
n&1&2&3&4&5 \\a_0&x&x^2-1&x^3-2x&x^4-3x^2+1&x^5-4x^3+3x\end{array}\end{equation}

One can notice that $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 1$ to further modify the formulas for $a_0$, but it doesn’t really get much better than this.

$$a_0 = \frac{({\lambda_1}^n-{\lambda_2}^n)x-({\lambda_1}^{n-1}-{\lambda_2}^{n-1})}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}$$

$$a_0 = x\cdot\left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{\lambda_1}^{n-1-k}{\lambda_2}^k\right)- \left( \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2}{\lambda_1}^{n-2-k}{\lambda_2}^k\right)$$

Comment: Eigenvalues of $M_x$ are $\lambda_i=\frac{x\pm \sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}$ and digonalizing matrix is $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1/ \lambda_1&1/ \lambda_2\end{array} \right)$. So ${M_x}^{n-1}\cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} x\\1 \end{array} \right)$ gives $a_0=\frac{x}{2^n}(\lambda_1^n-\lambda_2^n)+\lambda_1^{n-1}-\lambda_2^{n-1}$. If $n$ is odd, this is not coming as a polynomial in $x$. Isn't that wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are you sure there are no cancellations? Think of the Fibonacci sequence, for instance; its terms are always integers even though the general formula is in term of powers of the golden ratio $\varphi$ and its conjugate $\psi$.

Comment: It will be a great aid if you can give me the exact polynomial please.

Comment: I added an edit with the solution. You probably just miscalculated some things along the way.